# Is there a way to implement :hover entity to a link inline?

Tags: html, css, email, signature

I am working on an HTML email signature, which has to be done using rudimentary HTML. I have to use very simple CSS, tables and declare inline CSS for everything. All in all it works fine, but I have an issue with links. I can stripe the link to have no underline or color:

```
<a style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit!important;" href="https://#">link</a>
```

But don't know it is possible at all to add :hover entity inline?

```
a: hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You can use `<style></style>` wrappers and write them directly into the file. No? Then continue with normal CSS inside.

Comment: @Fizzand Unfortunately no. For signature, you can't use HTML head and body, just the HTML of the elements. I even tried declaring <style></style> with the elements, but the email readers didn't pick the styles up.

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent :hover in inline css.

You can give your anchor tag a class or id and change the property you need in there

```
<a class="anchor"> link </a>
```

Inside your css stylesheet

```
.anchor{ 
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

if you don't want to use external stylesheet you can add a onmouseover attribute to the element like so

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='none'" onmouseout="this.style.color='red'"> Link </a>
```

Comment: onmouseover will likely NEVER be executed in an email

Comment: This works in the browser, but email readers seemingly can't interpret this, so I can't really use it. I will probably just use permanent underline or slightly different color. Thansk! :-)

<a style="text-decoration: none;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" href="#">link</a>

Comment: @mplungjan Correct. I tested it with two different readers.

Answer (score 0):

The inline style have higher priority.

simply remove the `text-decoration: none;` from the element.

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none; 
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a style="color:inherit!important;" href="https://#">link</a>
```

another way is to add !important, but it's considered a bad habit:

```
a:hover{
   text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Comment: I would add that not only it's considered. It really is. Because the last snippet will change all the `a` tags on hover. Therefore if you want any anchor tag with different styling on hover it will be a pain in the ass to change it. There are very little use cases for `!important` and rule and we should save it for those :)